# Currency symbol is not shown for different locale

Tags: magento-1.9

I am using two different stores for two languages. First store for english and other for arabic language. I am using Saudi Riyal (SAR) as a default currency.

In Admin Panel > System > Configuration > General > Locale Option when I change locale option from English (United States) to Arabic (Saudi Arabia) the currency symbol SAR is not shown on frontend.

I want to change locale option for arabic store to translate english text into arabic from csv file. But when I change Locale Option the currency symbol is not shown on frontend.

Comment: any solutions ?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieved by Override the '**Magento\CurrencySymbol\Observer\CurrencyDisplayOptions**"
and customize the getCurrencyOptions($baseCode) function

Its solution in magento2.
maybe helps you

Answer (score 0):

You need to change how the currency is being displayed in your local.

Goto this file: root/lib/Zend/Locale/Data/en.xml (For English Language)

The above file shows how the currency is being displayed in English. If you want the same format in Arabic then open ar.xml file in the same folder and copy paste whatever is there between the currencyFormat tags from en.xml to ar.xml

Copy the contents of currentFormat tags from English to Arabic. I had the same issue. The currency symbol wouldn't show up in the Arabic locale. The above steps fixed it.